# How to compare two hours in erlang?

Tags: erlang

What is the way to compare two hours in erlang? The case is the following, 
I have a time limit to perform a transaction reversal eg: 30 minutes, if the 
time of the transaction to be reversed was more than 30 minutes ago I 
should not allow the transaction to be reversed. But I need to be able to 
compare the hours (from the transaction i want to revert and now hour) 
and I can not find any erlang function that compares hours, can someone help me?

```
LocalTime = calendar:local_time()
{{2017,11,7},{9,43,32}}
TransactionToRevertTime = {{2017,11,7},{9,23,36}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds/1` to convert the two datetimes to integers, subtract them, and check if their difference is greater than `30 * 60`:

```
1> A = {{2017,11,7},{9,43,32}}.
{{2017,11,7},{9,43,32}}
2> B = {{2017,11,7},{9,23,36}}.
{{2017,11,7},{9,23,36}}
3> C = {{2017,11,7},{9,0,36}}.
{{2017,11,7},{9,0,36}}
4> A1 = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(A).
63677267012
5> B1 = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(B).
63677265816
6> C1 = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(C).
63677264436
7> A1 - B1 > 30 * 60.
false
8> A1 - C1 > 30 * 60.
true
```

If A is now, B is less than 30 minutes ago while C is more than 30 minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Dogbert

Answer (score 1):

From the [Erlang Docs](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/time_correction.html):

"Take time stamps with `erlang:monotonic_time/0` and calculate the time difference using ordinary subtraction"

Take a difference between two calls to the `monotonic_time(second)` and if the difference it's bigger than 1800, more than 30 minutes have elapsed.

Comment: Probably better to use `monotonic_time/1` with `second` and comparing to `1800` instead of relying on the native time unit value (which is not guaranteed to be nanosecond).

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert, I have updated the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Thanks, but I use Dogbert way, his explanation was more clear, I'm new in erlang and his solution was the one I saw more clearly.